# Source .vimrc after map/function deletion

Tags: vim

I'd like to reload my `.vimrc` without restarting `vim`; the obvious answer is `:source $MYVIMRC`, but only works when I've scripted a **new** function/keymap, and fails if I've **deleted** one. For instance:

```
" empty .vimrc
" to which I've added L()

function! Temp()
    echo "ABC"
endfunc

:w | so ~/.vimrc
```

Now, `:call Temp()` will yield, as expected, "ABC".

```
" now, I've deleted Temp()
:w | so ~/.vimrc
```

...and `:call Temp()` still generates "ABC". Quitting and re-opening my .vimrc, however, would remove the function from memory entirely. Can I achieve that behavior with `:source`?

Comment: I am curious about the use case which is affected by this.

Comment: @Jean, I can't think of a convincing example, but assumed that I'd ultimately encounter some sort of problem related with un-removed keymaps. Anyway, I couldn't find an answer to the question elsewhere, and thought that I'd ask (out of curiosity)- perhaps someone else will also find this useful.

Comment: I remove `map d XXXXX` and the omap still exists, making dd too slow. After some trials, I exit nvim and restart. The problem is gone.  So I want a "clean" reload too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write a custom `:Reload` command that parses your `.vimrc` for function / command / mapping definitions, and `:delfunction` / `:delcommand` / `:unmap`s them. This is a considerable effort, and still unlikely to catch all cases. And all that to avoid a restart of Vim?!

Think hard whether you really need this (I cannot imagine any reason). We're talking about *a few seconds* of startup time, max. If you're concerned about having to re-open files etc., you can use the built-in `:mksession` for that (but again have to be careful what the session itself persists!)

Comment: This is super useful for quickly testing plugins you develop: if you have not written a script and instead did some changes (i.e. configuration variable/syntax/function/… definitions) that your plugin uses in runtime by hand it is easier to reload plugin then redo these changes. And this is much easier to do if you forget about parsing nonsense, instead using either “define and register” or “define in a special way” approach (frawor that allows reloading uses both approaches).

Comment: @ZyX: Agreed that reloading plugins during development makes sense; I use my [ReloadScript plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1904) for that. But even there, I don't care about remaining unused functions or mappings, and in those rare cases, I just restart.

Comment: With a plugin that just resources script you will have to somehow track dependencies in your mind and reload them in correct order. Unacceptable for plugins consisting of a large number of files. The intent for writing a frawor is the following: “I need correct reloading for complicated plugins”+“adding support for such reloading must be easy” ⇒ “as many functions as possible must be anonymous one; API functions must be available only once you specified file with their definition as dependency, frawor is responsible for copying funcrefs around”.

Comment: If I have a dependency graph and provide frawor with a scope dictionary it is really easy to 1) reload complicated plugins once its dependency changed (reload dependency and all dependants) and 2) reload plugin with many functions as this is as easy as wiping a scope dictionary and resourcing. Writing reloading of mappings, [auto]commands and functions was much easier then making core features (providing anonyomous API functions and reloading) work. Especially because first versions of frawor were assuming that plugins that need lazy loading should reside in plugin/ and not autoload/.

Comment: I use neovim-remote and abduco. With them, tmux is no more needed. In this situation,  exiting the entire nvim session is horrible